# How to setup .NET Launch order in JetBrains Rider for .NET Blazor/MAUI Application

Tags: .net, blazor, maui, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-rider

I know in Visual Studio I can arrange the projects launch order in the Configuration Manager by sorting the projects that are set to launch.

Like so (Visual Studio Configuration Manager Launch Order)

[image]

**How can I define this launch order in JetBrains Rider?**

In JetBrains, it seems that the IDE launches the projects in alphabetical order but I may need a specific launch order.

I was able to setup a launch order configuration that worked for me by renaming the .NET Launch Settings Profiles in JetBrains Rider with a prefix so they sorted/launched in alphabetical order.

like so (Screenshot of APIs Compound, where I forced an order by manually prefixing with letters in order I wanted to launch alphabetically)

[image]

I am then running my application by running the APIs compound first, then the 'Blazor' Compound, same thing for my MAUI config (APIs first, then MAUI Client)

[image]

Is there a more elegant solution to this in JetBrains Rider?

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Run_Debug_Multiple.html#compound-configs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rider 2023.3 they added `Multi-Launch configuration﻿`, you can read about how to set it up on https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/2023.3/Run_Debug_Multiple.html#multi_launch.

Here's a GIF from the documentation:

[image: Gif]

And here's a copy of the text:

[image]